# ServiceStack - SAML2

Tags: servicestack, saml-2.0

Is there some out of the box plugin for SAML2 auth or I would have to build mine from scratch?

If there's none, which library would you suggest, earlier I tried Kentor and I like how it's done, too bad I couldn't find their version of ServiceStack auth plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

There's a collection of plug-ins.

Don't roll your own!